# Finding out total worked hours and minutes formula

Tags: excel

```
FROM    TO      FROM    TO      FROM    TO
7:30 AM 2:00 PM 2:40 PM 2:40 PM 6:30 PM 12:00 AM
7:30 AM 2:00 PM 2:40 PM 2:40 PM 6:30 PM 12:00 AM
7:30 AM 2:00 PM 2:40 PM 2:40 PM 6:30 PM 12:00 AM
```

1. `HOUR(H2-C2)& "h"&MINUTE(H2-C2)&"m")`
2. `HOUR(F2-E2)&"h")`

Can you check what is the error in this formula:

```
(HOUR(H2-C2)& "h"&MINUTE(H2-C2)&"m")-(HOUR(F2-E2)&"h"& MINUTE(F2-E2)&"M")
```

I want the total hours worked by each person in this format: `12h48m`

Comment: Please delete your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25671745/excel-formula-for-finding-out-exact-value-from-first-to-second

Comment: The issue is that the times are crossing midnight, and there is no date information to tell Excel this.

Comment: How are deriving the result of 12h48m?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need the time between C2 and D2 added to the time between G2 and H2, that's what it looks like from your screenshot? You can also add in the difference between E2 and F2 if that's likely to be non-zero

You can use `MOD` function to handle times passing/on midnight, e.g.

`=MOD(D2-C2,1)+MOD(H2-G2,1)+MOD(F2-E2,1)`

Custom format result cell as `[h]:mm` and you'll get `12:00`, I'm not sure why it would be `12:48`. If you actually want it to display as `12h00m` then use a custom format for the result cell of

`[h]"h"mm"m"`

Comment: thank you thank you thank you i was serching for this long time nobody understoom me but you thak alot bye